# A followup if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

My question is a bit hard to describe so I have written a hypothetical code (nonfunctioning) down below and I wonder if there is a similar alternative in C#:

```
if (Red == true)
{ 
    i -= 3;
}
else if (Yellow == true)
{ 
    i -= 2
}
then
{
    list.Clear();
}
else{}
```

A "then" function of sorts that both `if` statements follow if one where to execute. The use of this would simply be so that I do not need to do in this case a `list.Clear();` in every if statement.

Comment: Is Red and Yellow bools?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no syntax construct like your *then* but you can create a method that clear the list and accept and returns the value to decrement

```
private int ClearAndDecrementBy(int decrement)
{
    list.Clear();
    return decrement;
}
```

and call it as

```
if(Red)
{ 
   i -= ClearAndDecrementBy(3);
}
else if(Yellow)
{ 
   i -= ClearAndDecrementBy(2);
}
else
{

}
```

Not really sure that there is any advantage though. The list should be declared at the global class level and this is never a good practice if it is needed only to make it work in this way. So, adding the call to *list.Clear* inside the if blocks seems more clear and it won't do any harm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Red == true)
{ 
  i -= 3;
}
else if(Yellow == true)
{ 
  i -= 2
}
else
{
}
if(Red == True || Yellow == true) //You can add more like: Blue == true
{
    list.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the "then" statement from your pseudo code and add the following line to the end of everything.

```
if (Red || Yellow)
{
   list.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Red || Yellow)
{
    i = Red ? -3 : -2;
    list.Clear();
}
else { }
```